# Добавить элемент в массив, если его там нет

Tags: php

Имеется код, функционал которого следующий:

Имеется массив данных с `id` товара и его количеством (реализация корзины товаров).

При переборе цикла производится условие поиска, и если перебираемый элемент равен `$product`, то количество прибавляется. Здесь проблем нет, но как добавить в массив данные, если их нет в массиве?

Пытался сделать вот так, но не получается. Но думаю суть вопроса ясна.

```
public function add($product, $count)
    {
        $array = json_decode('
            [{
                "product": "example-1",
                "count": "2"
            }, {
                "product": "example-2",
                "count": "3"
            }, {
                "product": "example-3",
                "count": "3"
            }]
        ');
        foreach($array as $row)
        {
            $products[] = $row;
            if($row->product == $product) $row->count = '20';
// Вот тут должен быть код, например если $product нет в массиве, то произвести функцию array_unshift($array, $product)
        }
        var_dump($products);
    }
```

Comment: Это не дубликат вопроса, в предыдущем вопросе - вопрос стоял в поиске элемента и прибавления, тут же наоборот если элемента нет в массиве, то прибавить, в противном случае производить continue;

Comment: В предыдущем вопросе я дал вам ответ отвечающий на оба этих вопроса

Comment: Добавил комментарий к предыдущему вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Вы не указали версию интерпретатора PHP на котором выполняются скрипты.*

Указанный код будет работать на версии PHP 7.0.0 и выше.
Если пользуетесь версией ниже 7.0.0 уберите объявление типов возвращаемых значений и объявление типов передаваемых параметров в функций (методы).

**Код класса:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Класс корзины
 */
class Cart
{
    protected $products;

    // Прочие свойста класса...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $productsInJSONFormat = '
            [{
                "product": "example-1",
                "count": "2"
            }, {
                "product": "example-2",
                "count": "3"
            }, {
                "product": "example-3",
                "count": "3"
            }]
        ';

        $this->products = json_decode($productsInJSONFormat);
    }

    /**
     *  Добавление товара в корзину или изменение количества
     */
    public function add(string $product, int $count = 1) : Cart
    {
        foreach ($this->products as $item) {
            if ($item->product == $product) {
                $item->count = $count;

                return $this;
            }
        }

        array_push($this->products, (object)['product' => $product, 'count' => $count]);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *  Удаление товара из корзины
     */
    public function remove(string $product) : Cart
    {
        if ($index = array_search($product, array_column($this->products, 'product'))) {
            unset($this->products[$index]);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Получить список продуктов в виде массива
     */
    public function getProducts(bool $json = false)
    {
        if ($json) {
            return json_encode(array_values($this->products));
        }

        return $this->products;
    }

    // Прочие методы класса...
}
```

**Пример использования:**

```
<?php

$cart = new Cart();

$cart->add('example-4', 10); // Добавит товар
$cart->add('example-1', 20); // Изменит количество
$cart->add('example-5'); // Добавит товар с количеством по умолчанию = 1

$cart->remove('example-2'); // Удалит товар

print_r($cart->getProducts()); // Получить и вывести массив товаров в корзине

echo "\n" . $cart->getProducts(true); // Получить и вывести массив товаров в корзине в JSON-формате
```

**Дополнительная информация:**

- [Объявление типов возвращаемых значений](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)
- [Объявление типов](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)